# String manipulation of Serial Port data

Tags: c#, string

I am working on creating a windows form application and I have come across a problem.  I am reading data in from the serial port.

```
string RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
```

This works fine but what I now want to do is extract values from my `RxString` and put them into their own string arrays.

This the RxString format:

```
GPS:050.1347,N,00007.3612,WMAG:+231\r\n
```

it repeats itself as more data is added from the serial port the numbers change but stay the same length, and the + changes to -.  I want to put the numbers between GPS: and ,N into one string array, the numbers between N, and ,W in another string array and finally the numbers between + and \r\n in a 3rd string array.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This can be done pretty easily with regex. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try String.Split(...)

Comment: No question is stupid when the doubt is genuine.

Comment: I have tried string spit but could not work out how to use it don't under stand how it would work if I have MAG: "data to extract" \r\n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Regex solution:

```
        string pattern = @"^GPS:(?<gps>.{8}),N,(?<n>.{10}),WMAG:(\+|\-)(?<wmag>.{3})\\r\\n$";

        string gps = string.Empty;
        string n = string.Empty;
        string wmag = string.Empty;

        string input = @"GPS:050.1347,N,00007.3612,WMAG:+231\r\n";

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        if (regex.IsMatch(input))
        {
            Match match = regex.Match(input);

            foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["gps"].Captures)
                gps = capture.Value;

            foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["n"].Captures)
                n = capture.Value;

            foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["wmag"].Captures)
                wmag = capture.Value;
        }

        Console.Write("GPS: ");
        Console.WriteLine(gps);

        Console.Write("N: ");
        Console.WriteLine(n);

        Console.Write("WMAG: ");
        Console.WriteLine(wmag);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: That is awesome thanks man :-) There is one problem, I forgot to mention this in my question but the value 225 after WMAG:+ changes between a 1, 2 and 3 digit number.
In the string pattern, how do I say the length of the number after WMAG is 1 or 2 or 3 digits long. I tried this but it doesnt work:

`string pattern = @"^GPS:(?<gps>.{8}),N,(?<n>.{10}),WMAG:(\+|\-)(?<wmag>.{3|2|1})\\r\\n$";`

Comment: @JamesArcher Change it to `(?<wmag>.{1,3})`

Comment: @JamesArcher Any feedback so far? Don't forget to mark as correct the anser that most helped  you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

string latitude = RxString.Split(',')[0].Substring(4);
string longitude = RxString.Split(',')[2];
string mag = RxString.Split(',')[3].Substring(6).Trim();
```

Comment: @JamesArcher This won't work if WMAG changes length from 1 to 3 chars.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always the same length, the best way is to use `substring()` method.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the _best_ solution, but it may be the easiest to code.

Comment: By best I mean fastest. RegEx are slower than `substring()`

Comment: string RxString;// where the raw serial data is stored
string[] mag;//where magnetic data is stored 
int i;//mag pointer

 RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();//ready data from serial port into string
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));//invoke allows it to call function diplay text

            int i = RxString.LastIndexOf("MAG:");

            if (i != -1)
                mag = RxString.Substring(i+5, 3);

Comment: Thanks man :-)

`string RxString;// where the raw serial data is stored
string[] mag;//where magnetic data is stored 
int i;//mag pointer

 RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();//ready data from serial port into string
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));//invoke allows it to call function diplay text

            int i = RxString.LastIndexOf("MAG:");`

            if (i != -1)
                mag = RxString.Substring(i+5, 3);`

The value in string mag gets overwritten by the next value each time at the moment. How do I make string mag and array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's some RegEx that could make this prettier, but I'm not great at regex so I'd checkout C#'s String.Split function.  Substring would work if you know the numbers will be the same length, but if that's not a guarantee, Split would be your best bet. 
You could split each line on the comma, creating an array, then use Replace to remove the extra text (like GPS: and WMAG:), if you know that's going to be the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution since it uses "magic" numbers and substrings - but may work for your situation since you said the string length is always the same.

```
var serialPortInfo = "GPS:050.1347,N,00007.3612,WMAG:+231\r\n";

private List<string> value1 = new List<string>();
private List<string> value2 = new List<string>();
private List<string> value3 = new List<string>();

private void populateValues(string s)
{
    // this should give an array of the following: 
    // values[0] = "050.1347"
    // values[1] = "N"
    // values[2] = "00007.3612"
    // values[3] = "WMAG:+231"
    //
    var values = (s.Substring(4, (s.Length - 8))).Split(','); 

    // populate lists
    //
    value1.Add(values[0]);
    value2.Add(values[2]); 
    value3.Add(values[3].Substring(6, 3));
}

//usage
populateValues(serialPortInfo);
```